# how to solve Error in Deveco studio emulator

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, deveco-studio

I donot know to operate emulator on dev eco studio I verified my mail but unfortunately I got this error (Query remote devices error: Access token refresh fail)

what should I do to solve this

I tried to restart the program many times bit in vain